# linear combination

Tags: vector-spaces

If $\mathbb C$ is the field of complex numbers which vectors in $\mathbb C^3$ are linear combinations of $(1,0,-1)$,$(0,1,1)$ and$(1,1,1)$?

Please help.

Comment: Since you're new here, I'd like mention that it would help if you show what you have already tried. This lets us know where you got stuck, and allows us to better answer your question.  Also, showing your work demonstrates that you have invested some time in the problem, which increases the likelihood of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: ok....please tell how to give a proper title

Comment: @Dave In a linear combination, the scalars you multiply the 3 vectors by can indeed all be zero (consult any decent text or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination#Definition and you will see there is no rule that says any of the scalars has to be nonzero).  This is important because the set of all linear combinations of the vectors, or "span" of the vectors, should always be a subspace of the larger vector space for any vector space.

Comment: @Dave : exactly what kind of answer are they looking for?  Can you just say $S =\{c_1\langle 1, 0, -1\rangle + c_2\langle 0, 1, 1\rangle + c_3\langle 1, 1, 1\rangle \mid c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbf{C}\}$?

Comment: @Dave : Sorry, I was a little confused becuase I am used to working with real vector spaces, but if you read user1551's answer and use it successfully it makes my previous question pretty pointless.  You'll see.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\det\pmatrix{1&0&−1\\ 0&1&1\\ 1&1&1}=1\neq0$.